# How to get rid of the error with merging year and month column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

how can I get rid of error with *date_one* and *date_two*:

> TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable

and with date_three I get:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'assign'

My code

```
df = pd.read_csv('co2_mm_mlo.csv', comment='#', sep=',', index_col=False)
print(df, '\n')
df['date_one'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df['year'], month=df['month']), format='%Y%m')
df['date_two'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month']].assign(Day=1)).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
df['date_three'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)[['year','month','day']]).dt.to_period('m')
df = df.set_index('date_one')
print(df, '\n')
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? `AxesSubplot` suggests you're trying to plot something but I don't see your code calling a plot method - could you please clarify?

Comment: I want to merge two columns 'year' and 'month' to get 'date' as a result

Comment: if they're string columns, just add them and parse; `pd.to_datetime(df['year']+df['month'], format='%Y%m')`